# Google DNS records not resolving

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I have setup our internal domain on a Google Cloud DNS Zone.  Then I pointed my computer to the Zone's name servers and 8.8.8.8 for fallback/public IPs.  I can resolve all my internal addresses fine and most public addresses as well.  For some reason, the DNS names for Google sites are not resolving.  For example, the following do not resolve:

www.google.com

www.gmail.com

www.youtube.com

Any ideas on how to fix this?

UPDATE

$dig www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 14289
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.     300 IN  SOA ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com. dns-admin.google.com. 1 21600 3600 1209600 300

;; Query time: 29 msec
;; SERVER: 216.239.32.108#53(216.239.32.108)
;; WHEN: Fri Mar 13 12:49:36 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 104

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then I pointed my computer to the Zone's name servers and 8.8.8.8 for fallback/public IPs.

Don't do that. You need to set your computer to use a DNS resolver to access things from the internet. The Cloud DNS nameservers will not answer questions for anything other than the zones they host - they are "authoritative" servers, not "resolvers". 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are Google's public DNS resolvers - they answer questions for anything on the Internet not because they actually "own" that data, but because they go off and make queries on your behalf to discover the answer from authoritative servers.

If your zone was public, this would be all there was to it - the resolver would work down the tree to find your zone and then give you the answer. There would be no special configuration. But if this zone is private - you didn't buy a domain or create it in a domain that already exists - you'll need to do some extra work because nobody on the internet can find it unless they know where to look. You'll need to run your own resolver that knows to do something different and private for this kind of name. That's called a 'view'. At that point you could consider just hosting the data directly on that server.

Answer (score 0):

The name server's that cloud dns mentions is something you might have configured in your domain config. whereas 8.8.8.8 is the google public dns resolved. Both aren't the same. What does your dig command show for google sites when resolved via 8.8.8.8?